# Use git clone in PyCharm and save to a particular folder

Tags: python, git, pycharm, jetbrains-ide

I want to clone a repository and save it in a particular folder.
Usually in jupyter we would use :

```
! git clone 'url'{paths['folder name']}
```

But I am not sure how to do the same in PyCharm, it's quite confusing.
Can anyone please help me with this?

PS: Using VCS will help clone but then how do we save it in the particular path without manual effort?

Comment: Can't you use `$ git clone <remote_dir_url> <relative_path_to_local_folder>` ?